# Is there a difference between a generic part and a Dell part?

Tags: network-adapter, compatibility

I was wondering if there would any difference between a generic intelligence pro1000 pci e NIC and a Dell branded one.

Would the firmware be any different? Would the hardware it would work with be different?

There are cheap cards on ebay but they are pulled from Dell servers so I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drivers seem to be based on the major chipset not on the board manufacturer. I would expect an "Intel Pro/1000" driver to work on the both Dell-branded and third-party NICs using the Intel Pro/1000 chipset.

Comment: Okay that's what I need to know. Time to buy!

Answer (score 0):

There is no functional differnce between the parts, both will work just the same. The drivers and firmware for the devices would be different. Both should work just fine.